# Oracle, Syntax Error ORA00907

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008

I am using `Case` statement in the `Where` condition. When I am trying to use this condition I am getting the results

```
AND ( XF.SRC_KEY NOT IN (3, 17) 
OR UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN ('AVONEX') END;
```

But when I tried to extend the case statement I am getting Syntax error as `Missing Right Parenthesis`.

```
AND ( XF.SRC_KEY NOT IN (3, 17) 
OR UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN ('AVONEX') 
WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 17 THEN ('AVONEX','TECFIDERA') END;
```

Please find the Entire Query for reference :

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM ods_ims_1 x,
       ods_lh_ims_2 xf,
       ods_prod_master pm,
       lh_ods.ods_week_time_dimn t
 WHERE x.ims_spp_key = xf.ims_supplier_id (+)
   AND x.ndc_no = pm.ndc_no (+)
   AND (xf.src_key NOT IN (3, 17)
           OR UPPER(pm.trade_name) NOT IN CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN ('AVONEX') END
           --WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 17 THEN ('AVONEX','TECFIDERA') END
           OR TRUNC(MONTH_END_DT) >= CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN '31-OCT-14' ELSE '31-JAN-13' END)
   AND t.week_time_dimn_key = x.week_time_dimn_key;
```

Comment: Logically your second condition is contained in your first.

Comment: Yes, but can you please let me know why the Syntax error (missing right parenthesis) is coming? I added one more WHEN statement with proper syntax

Comment: This error does not have to be about parenthesis. Various syntax errors can trigger it.

Comment: Try `... THEN (SELECT 'AVONEX','TECFIDERA' FROM dual)`

Comment: Tried, now I got different error "Too many Values"
  OR UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN (CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN 'AVONEX'
      WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 17 THEN (SELECT 'AVONEX','TECFIDERA' FROM DUAL) END)

Comment: If we use this command the data will be split into two columns but I am having the data in Same Column

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using deprecated `JOIN` syntax, updating to explicit `JOIN` syntax clears up the `WHERE` criteria, then you can clean up your `WHERE` criteria by getting rid of the `CASE` expression when it requires multiple outputs, as it causes the problem you noticed.  I believe this should work:

```
SELECT X.*
FROM ODS_IMS_1 X
LEFT JOIN ODS_LH_IMS_2 XF
  ON  X.IMS_SPP_KEY = XF.IMS_SUPPLIER_ID
LEFT JOIN ODS_PROD_MASTER PM
  ON  X.NDC_NO = PM.NDC_NO
JOIN LH_ODS.ODS_WEEK_TIME_DIMN T
  ON  T.WEEK_TIME_DIMN_KEY = X.WEEK_TIME_DIMN_KEY
WHERE XF.SRC_KEY NOT IN (3, 17)
   OR (XF.SRC_KEY = 3 AND UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) <> 'AVONEX')
   OR (XF.SRC_KEY = 17 AND UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN  ('AVONEX','TECFIDERA'))
   OR TRUNC(MONTH_END_DT) >= CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN '31-OCT-14' ELSE '31-JAN-13' END
```

Note: If I messed up the `JOIN` conversion in some way, you can still get your criteria to work with:

```
SELECT X.*
FROM ODS_IMS_1 X, ODS_LH_IMS_2 XF, ODS_PROD_MASTER PM, LH_ODS.ODS_WEEK_TIME_DIMN T
WHERE X.IMS_SPP_KEY = XF.IMS_SUPPLIER_ID(+)
AND X.NDC_NO = PM.NDC_NO(+)
AND (       XF.SRC_KEY NOT IN (3, 17)
        OR (XF.SRC_KEY = 3 AND UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN ('AVONEX'))
        OR (XF.SRC_KEY = 17 AND UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN ('AVONEX','TECFIDERA'))
        OR TRUNC(MONTH_END_DT) >= CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN '31-OCT-14' ELSE '31-JAN-13' END
        )
AND T.WEEK_TIME_DIMN_KEY = X.WEEK_TIME_DIMN_KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that the first condition works, but the second doesn't. The first

```
AND ( XF.SRC_KEY NOT IN (3, 17) 
 OR UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN ('AVONEX') END;
```

is clearly missing a right parenthesis, as is the second:

```
AND ( XF.SRC_KEY NOT IN (3, 17)
 OR UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN ('AVONEX') 
    WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 17 THEN ('AVONEX','TECFIDERA') END;
```

In each case the missing parenthesis could be placed after the `END` of the `CASE`.

That said, I'm not sure this syntax would work even with the missing parenthesis. In fact, I am pretty sure it would not. It would be better to write the condition this way, I think:

```
AND ( XF.SRC_KEY NOT IN (3, 17)
   OR XF.SRC_KEY = 3 AND UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) != 'AVONEX'
   OR XF.SRC_KEY = 17 AND UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN ('AVONEX','TECFIDERA') ); -- note closing parenthesis
```

If you're wedded to using a `CASE` statement then you can achieve what you're trying to do using `REGEXP_LIKE()`:

```
AND ( XF.SRC_KEY NOT IN (3,17)
   OR REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME), CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN '^AVONEX$' WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 17 THEN '^AVONEX|TECFIDERA$') END );
```

-- but that's a bit klunky and esoteric, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Hi David thanks for researching into this and sorry for confusion. I am getting a syntax error with this Line only
AND ( XF.SRC_KEY NOT IN (3, 17) 
OR UPPER(PM.TRADE_NAME) NOT IN CASE WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 3 THEN ('AVONEX') 
WHEN XF.SRC_KEY = 17 THEN ('AVONEX','TECFIDERA') END;
 so I have ended the statement here please refere to my full query once